# How to check if two hashed string belong to same clear text password

Tags: hash, md5, java-security, scrypt, java-security-manager

Recently I am stuck in a problem related to password encoding/decoding and matching and updating the same in db, need your help guys.
Problem goes like below -

1. User comes to the portal creates the account for which data is
   stored in the db(for example name it db1) with account_name and
   hashed_password
2. Now I have to move this data to another db(for example name it db2) where same data can be already present.
3. Now while moving the data I have to identify if the hashed password stored in the db1 and db2 is for the same clear text password and decide to do -

   - If matched then update the same row b.
   - If not matched insert the new row

How can I match the encoded values of the same clear text password(even they are for the same because every-time hashing runs it creates the new hash string)

I am using the inbuilt java security api and Scrypt/MD5/Legacy algorithm.

Comment: I'd recommend not using the password this way (for testing whether or not two things are the same).  Without access to the original password you won't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Joe for your opinion. I really appreciate. And let's see if I can get the solution.